# ButterKnife onClick custom view

Tags: android, butterknife

I've created a custom button and tried to use `ButterKnife` `@onClick` annotation, but it's not working.

Is it possible to use `ButterKnife` for custom views like this or I will have to use the default `onClickListener`?

CustomButton

```
public class CustomButton extends RelativeLayout {

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.button_layout, this);
}
```

Menu

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}

@OnClick(R.id.button_play)
public void onButtonPlayClicked() {
    // NOT CALLED
}
```

Menu Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_pattern"
android:padding="15dp">

<com.example.ui.custom.CustomButton
    android:id="@+id/button_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

Currently, I encounter the same problem and found a pretty nice solution.
I override **setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)** inside my view and assign listener to my button. After that **@OnClick** works as expected.

In your case you may add the next method:

```
@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickLister l) {
   ButterKnife.findById(this.getView(), R.id.button_play).setOnClickLister(l);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

> Custom views can bind to their own listeners by not specifying an ID.

```
public class FancyButton extends Button {
    @OnClick
    public void onClick() {
        // TODO do something!
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but this do not work. I need to use `@onClick` on the CustomButton from the Activity

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same problem. I solved by handling event dispatch in my custom view.

In your case:

```
public class CustomButton extends RelativeLayout {

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(hasOnClickListeners()) {
                callOnClick();
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, I had the same problem as OP and your peace of code solved the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a fix!

Replace the root view of your custom view's XML (*R.layout.button_layout*) to use `<merge>` instead. As you can read in the ButterKnife documentation:

> Bind a view's children into fields using ButterKnife.bind(this). **If you use `<merge>` tags in a layout and inflate in a custom view constructor you can call this immediately after**. Alternatively, custom view types inflated from XML can use it in the onFinishInflate() callback.

In my case I replaced:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_button_default"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:padding="@dimen/normal_padding"
tools:background="@color/white"
tools:layout_height="80dp">
```

By:

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Now, the parent view configuration is inside the CustomView initialization method. All the OnClick and OnLongClick events are working!

Hope this could help!

Comment: yes this work! But I also added code setClickable(true); inside custom view class. Because I will need clieckable root view

Answer (score -1):

```
In your activity try to add..

 ButterKnife.inject(this);
check this code

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ButterKnife.inject(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonAlert)
public void alertClicked(View v){
new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
    .setMessage(getFormattedMessge())
    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .show();
 }
```

Comment: This code work for the default views not the custom ones. unfortunally